# MySQL Plugin "mysql_old_password" not loaded

Tags: mysql, password, plugins, macos, homebrew

In an attempt to fix another issue I had, I ran the commands below (as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/old-client.html)

```sql
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_old_password'
mysql> WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
    -> 'root'@'localhost' = OLD_PASSWORD('new_password');
```

And now I'm unable to even get access to mysql through `mysql -u root` because it gives me the error `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql_old_password' is not loaded`.  I can't run `mysqladmin` and `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` gives me the error

```shell
[1] 51759
my-username@Macbook-Pro ~ % 
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

When I tried to run `mysqld --old-password=1` I got a whole lot of  `2022-08-17T11:10:18.149573Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling using homebrew for macOS, when that didn't work I also tried manually installing mysql from the website but that didn't work either.

(I use mysql version 8.0.30 for macOS 12.4)

Answer (score 0):

Was given the following post on GitHub to properly uninstall MySQL so that I could reinstall it again and have it work correctly: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d

[image: GitHub Post by VitorBritto to properly uninstall MySQL]

[image: A comment on that post to properly uninstall MySQL on Apple Silicon devices]